# Highcharts Area chart gradient fill

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

How can I get chart like this with Highcharts.
I can't get gradient fill of chart like this:

[image: chart]

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can use linear gradient in case of your chart. You can find information about this gradient on Highcharts website: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors

```
  fillColor: {
    linearGradient: {
      x1: 0,
      x2: 0,
      y1: 0,
      y2: 1
    },
    stops: [
      [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]],
      [0.8, hexToRgba(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2], 0)]
    ]
  }
```

You can use stacking: normal to have your area series on top of each other and marker.fillColor to make white fill on all of your markers.

```
plotOptions: {
  area: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    marker: {
      symbol: 'circle',
      lineWidth: 2,
      fillColor: 'white',
      lineColor: null,
    }
  }
},
```

Here you can find an example how it can work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bLdhefff/6/

Best regards.